# Course in python i got stuck

Tags: python

Write a function isprime(n) to return True if n is a prime number, and False otherwise! Use docstring """Checks if n is a prime number""". Recall that a positive integer is a prime number if it's only divisible by 1 and itself. The first few prime numbers are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ... Do not change the main program. Expected output:

```
0: False
1: False
2: True
11: True
111: False
10001: False
104729: True
```

Hint:
If n < 2 then it is not a prime number. Check this first. Then use a for loop with index i = 2, 3, ..., n-1. The modulo operator % will help you decide if n is divisible by i.

Hint_2:
First write the docstring.
Use a condition which makes the function return False if n < 2.
Use a for loop with index i going over 2, 3, ..., n-1.
In the body of the for loop, use a condition which checks if n is divisible by i. Use the modulo operator % for that.
If so, return False.
After the loop ends, return True.
Note: This is not the most efficient algorithm, but it's OK for now.

My Code:

```
def isprime(n):
    
    """Checks if n is a prime number"""
    x = 1
    if n < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for x in range(104729):
            x = x+1
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
            x = x+1
            return True
    
    
    

# Main program (do not change):
print("0:", isprime(0))
print("1:", isprime(1))
print("2:", isprime(2))
print("11:", isprime(11))
print("111:", isprime(111))
print("10001:", isprime(10001))
print("104729:", isprime(104729))
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You'll have to move your `return True` in a bit - right now it's returning after the first iteration of the `for` loop. There is also no need to manually increment `x` - use the value directly from your `range` statement, but make sure to start on a value different than 0. `for x in range(2, 104729)`

Comment: You have slightly over complicated this IMO. You could just use: `def prime(n):` `return not any(n%i == 0 for i in range(2, n)) if n > 1 else False`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I didn't feel like taking the time to write a explanation which is why I commented and did not answer. For students, learning to understand code is a great exercise. Through further investigation he could understand my code and learn something along the way all while being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @EliHarold that's fine. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use a debugger. Really. You'll be a much better programmer if you know what a debugger is and how to use it. And it's not hard. You can gain much it in 1 day.

Step 1: get an IDE which has a debugger. Don't run your programs on console. A good and free IDE is PyCharm.

Step 2: Set a breakpoint on the first line of the main program.

Step 3: Click "Step into" if you reach a method call. Click "Step over" for other statements.

Step 4: Find the window where all variables are displayed and see them updating step by step.

Step 5: Profit. You'll see what your program does and where it goes wrong.

---

Try debugging it yourself, then check the spoilers.

> a) `for x in range(...):` is already incrementing `x`, you don't need `x=x+1`, otherwise you'll increase even more.

> b) the loop starts at 0. If you want to start the loop at 2, use `range(2, ...)`.

> c) the indentation of the `return True` is in a place where it returns from the method on the first iteration of the `for` loop. Python is sensitive to indentation.

---

BTW: your code is limited to 104729. You might want to replace that by `n`.

There are some mathematical optimization possible as well, but these may not be your first points of interest.

a) dividing by multiples of 2 is not needed if you have already tested for division by 2. If you treat 2 as a special case, you can start the loop at 3 and increase in steps of 2.

b) dividing by numbers that are more than the half of `n` is pointless, because the result will always be smaller than 2.

c) if you think about b) even more, you'll find that dividing by numbers larger than sqrt(n) is pointless, because the result will always be smaller than the values you have already tried.

Comment: :O How do you make spoilers???

Comment: @EliHarold `>! Text`

Comment: It's worth noting also that if you don't replace 104729 with `n` as you suggested, it will return `False` for any `n` less than that value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided in the comments under your post. I updated the for loop so that you are not limited to 104729.  See below:

```
def isprime(n):

    """Checks if n is a prime number"""
    x = 1
    if n < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for x in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
        return True


# Main program (do not change):
print("0:", isprime(0))
print("1:", isprime(1))
print("2:", isprime(2))
print("11:", isprime(11))
print("111:", isprime(111))
print("10001:", isprime(10001))
print("104729:", isprime(104729))
```

Answer (score -1):

you did not give value to the "n" probably main problem in there.
have good day :)

Comment: n is passed as a parameter, e.g. 11 in print("11:", isprime(11)). It has a value